# How to force browser DOMDocument.ExecCommand() function to inject <font> tags for default font

Tags: html, css, dom, fonts, execcommand

Scenario:
My web application allows users to type and send emails:

```
<div contenteditable="true">User can type email contents here</div>
```

While they are composing their email, they have the ability to highlight some text, and select a new font to change that text to. The way this is implemented is to call the ExecCommand command on the DOMDocument object to allow the browser to apply this font-style to the highlighted text.

```
domDocument.ExecCommand("fontname", false, "Arial Black");
```

The way most browsers apply this font-change is to inject a  tag into the DOM surrounding the highlighted text:

```
<font face='Arial Black'> highlighted text here </font> Here is some more text that was not highlighted.
```

This works fine for all font except for the browser's default font ('Times New Roman' for most browsers). If I highlight some text and select 'Times New Roman', I have noticed IE9+ has an optimization in place to realize that this font is already in 'Times New Roman' (because it is the default browser font), and to not inject a redundant  tag into the the DOM. This is fine while the email is still displayed in the current browser, as the font is defaulting to 'Times New Roman' anyway. However, when the email is sent and opened in another client, the  tag is not sent with the email since it was never injected into the DOM, thus the client rendering the email can use whatever default font it want, which is not necessary 'Times New Roman'.

I have created a JSFiddle to show this problem. See comments in code for usage:
http://jsfiddle.net/8xq4dpb2/1/

Does anyone have any ideas to cleanly inject the font information into the page? Or is the only option to manually 'hack' the DOM to include this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Few Points to consider

1. use Span instead of adding font tag in your DOM.
2. Then add specific class for font to that span
3. Better use Jquery to call the function rather then onClick() inline function call.

I have created a solution for you please refer this : -http://jsbin.com/janukeyeya/5/edit You can see toggle of font for div.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I think you are slightly misunderstanding my question though. I want to be able to highlight a subset of the text, and then change the font on that exact text only. This is tricky because there is not necessary a DOM element wrapping exactly this text, thus one needs to be injected. domDocument.ExecCommand provides this functionality, however seems to fail in the default font case in my scenario above.

Comment: So if you wrap the selected text with span, will that do your work?

Comment: Also to address your points:

1) Yes spans are better, but the <font> tag is added by the browser itself. Not my implementation. 
2) This works in the general case, however as mentioned above, I don't want to style an entire <span>. Only the sub set of text highlighted by the user. 
3) Yes this would be better. Hacked this together since my issue was not with onClick events

Comment: yes that would work, but I have to then write logic to identity the selected text and inject a span into the DOM. This is tricky logic and hard to write cross-browser support. Wondering if there is a cleaner way to this.

Comment: Ok let me try to give you proper solution

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/janukeyeya/5/edit Select some portion of text with mouse and then click button